# Save Backup Files to DropBox folder in Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, dropbox, file-transfer, database-backups

I am trying to create a PowerShell Script to backup my databases to a specific DropBox folder.

I started with my Windows Firewall, utilizing the netsh firewall call, and that works just fine.  My Firewall rules have been saved successfully to my specified DropBox folder.

However, I tried a similar approach to backup my Databases to the same folder, it failed with an Access Denied error.  If I change the folder to a local root folder, such as C:\DatabaseBackup, the following Firewall Script works fine.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue with DropBox?  I tried to visit the DropBox site and they do offer an API, but I have no idea how to use it or if it can be used at all.
I found another site with there is an uploaded script, but it is a BASH .sh script for Unix and linus and I do not want to install the WSL on my Server for strict security reasons.

```
netsh advfirewall export "C:\Users\xyxAbc\Dropbox\VPSBACKUP\vps-fw-rules.wfw"


[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null
$s = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $instance


###  Script A (failed with "Access Denied".

$bkdir = "C:\Users\xyxAbc\Dropbox\VPSBACKUP"
$dbs = $s.Databases
foreach ($db in $dbs) 
{
     if($db.Name -ne "tempdb" -or $db.Name -ne "master" -or $db.Name -ne 'model' -or $db.Name -ne'msdb') 
     {
         $dbname = $db.Name
         # $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmm #We use this to create a file name based on the timestamp 
         $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
         $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
         $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
         $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + ".bak", "File")
         $dbBackup.SqlBackup($s)
     }
}


###  Script B  (Succeded without issues)

$bkdir = "C:\DatabaseBackup"
$dbs = $s.Databases
foreach ($db in $dbs) 
{
     if($db.Name -ne "tempdb" -or $db.Name -ne "master" -or $db.Name -ne 'model' -or $db.Name -ne'msdb') 
     {
         $dbname = $db.Name
         # $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmm #We use this to create a file name based on the timestamp 
         $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
         $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
         $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
         $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + ".bak", "File")
         $dbBackup.SqlBackup($s)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with this process.  When DropBox is installed on my Server, I noticed a huge reduction of Disk Space all over sudden.  For some odd reason, DropBox tried to bring my 1000 Gig space into that small 60 Gig Hard Drive, which created a reduced resources problem.

I removed and deleted all the DropBox reference from the Server and created a brand new DropBox account that will only support that Server backup needs.  then, I shared that Folder with my 1000Gig account and was able to see it from my other computers.